# how to specify the port when running PhantomJSDriver

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm using `phantomjs2.1.1`, `com.github.detro.phantomjsdriver:1.2.0` to run automatic webui tests,

when im running `phantomjsdriver`, could someone tell me how can i specify the running port? i want to run `phantomjsdriver` on port 6666

below is the output log:

```
INFO: executable: /Users/wtnull/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs
Mar 12, 2016 1:50:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 8852
Mar 12, 2016 1:50:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=8852, --webdriver-logfile=/Users/wtnull/yeepay/ypt/branches/default/ypt-script-sdk/phantomjsdriver.log]
Mar 12, 2016 1:50:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {} [INFO  - 2016-03-12T05:50:17.729Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8852
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I read the source code, I found the solution.

I can choose to use `PhantomJSDriverService.Build()...build()` to create a phantomJSDriverService,
and get phantomjsDriver instance by `new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJSDriverService, new DesiredCapabilities())`

In the `Build()`, which is inner class of `PhantomJSDriverService`, I could specify the port to run phantomjsdriver, below is the code detail.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities()
caps.javascriptEnabled = true
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')

phantomJSDriver = new PhantomJSDriver((new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder())
.usingPhantomJSExecutable(PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(caps, "https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki", "http://phantomjs.org/download.html"))
"https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/downloads"))
.usingPort(6666)
.withProxy(null)
.withLogFile(new File("phantomjsdriver.log"))
.usingCommandLineArguments(PhantomJSDriverService.findCLIArgumentsFromCaps(caps, "phantomjs.cli.args"))
.usingGhostDriverCommandLineArguments(PhantomJSDriverService.findCLIArgumentsFromCaps(caps, "phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args")                                    .build(), caps)
```

the oupput log is :

```
Mar 13, 2016 3:15:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
Mar 13, 2016 3:15:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 6666
Mar 13, 2016 3:15:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=6666, --webdriver-logfile=/Users/wtnull/yeepay/ypt/branches/default/ypt-script-sdk/phantomjsdriver.log]
Mar 13, 2016 3:15:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2016-03-13T07:16:01.085Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 6666
```